# Rails nested model validation only runs when something is filled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-attributes

I have a form that looks something like this:

```
<%= form_with model: @user, url: wizard_path, method: :patch, local: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :asset_transfers do |asset_transfer_form| %>
    <%= asset_transfer_form.text_field :account_number, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
    <div class="invalid-feedback"> <%= @user.errors.messages[:"asset_transfers.account_number"].join(", ") %> </div>
    <%= asset_transfer_form.text_field :institution_number, class: "form-control" %>
    <div class="invalid-feedback"><%= @user.errors.messages[:"asset_transfers.institution_number"].join(", ") %></div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Here's my association:

```
user.rb
has_many :asset_transfers, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :asset_transfers, allow_destroy: true

asset_transfer.rb
belongs_to :user
validates :account_number, :institution_number, presence: true, numericality: true
```

When I fill out my form, if I submit blank for both fields, no errors show up and `@user.save` returns `true`. However, if I type in a random string
in one of the fields and submit, errors show up and `@user.save` now returns false. I really have no idea why this is happening and couldn't find anything related on Google. Appreciate for any help!

EDIT: These fields are of type `bigint`. I wrote a migration to change them to `string` and it's working fine now. When I submit with nothing filled in, I see errors for them being blank and not a number. Still interested to know why validations didn't work with `bigint` though.

Comment: describe desired behaviour

Comment: I would expect to see errors when I submit the form with nothing filled in because of the `presence: true` validation and `@user.save` should also be false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [`reject_if: :all_blank`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) check to your `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to not allow empty nested entries despite of the data types.

Comment: Do you have any ideas why validations didn't run when the fields are of type `bigint` when nothing is filled out though? When I changed them to `string`, I didn't need this check to see errors.

Comment: No, not really. Might have something to do with how params are being passed and maybe when the column is `string` Rails treated empty fields as empty strings. But you better concentrate on making things working exactly as you need them to instead of guessing why they don't. Add some specs to double check if you write tests.

Comment: Strings work for me. The only reason I had them as `bigint` in the first place was because those numbers can be long and since they are numbers, I thought I'd use `bigint` to prevent overflowing. But strings works just as well if I have a validation for `numeric: true`. I'll definitely add tests for this weird case, thanks for your help!